# How to get model saved in session with @ModelAttribute parameter annotation?

Tags: spring-mvc, session, session-variables, modelattribute

In my controller advice I have put one model object in HttpSession session:

```
Map<String, Game> gamesMap = new HashMap<>();
gamesMap.put("1", new Game());

Games games = new Games();
games.setGames(gamesMap);

session.setAttribute("games", games);
```

When I try to get that object with @ModelAttribute parameter `games.getGames()` returns me always null instead of the gamesMap I've set before.

```
RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String test(@ModelAttribute("games") Games games) {
   games.getGames(); // getGames() returns null instead of collection I've set before.
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? When I use session and get it from there it works fine, but I'm trying to understand why it doesn't work with @ModelAttribute which is more cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found what the issue was. Spring only tries to bind model attribute to session parameter if the controller is annotated with `@sessionattributes`. If it doesn't find that it creates new instance in which case the map was null.